# What is the DarkImages folder in Visual Studio used for?

Tags: image, visual-studio, button

I am working on a project in Visual Studio. Every time when I created a button, an image will be generated automatically in the Images folder. And I noticed that this image will also be generated in the DarkImages folder:

[image]

The code only takes references to the Images folder. What is the usage of the DarkImages folder? Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, asked my boss, he provided a clue.
The image in the DarkImages could be used when someone wants to switch to the dark mode. And that would be where they would look for the dark version of the images.